# How to maintain the client credentials to a report server and maintain these credentials until it reaches a SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report

> Error al representar el cliente.  Error al procesar el informe.
> (rsProcessingAborted)  No se puede crear una conexión al origen de
> datos 'CN_DesarrolloRegional'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)  Error de
> inicio de sesión del usuario 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Sorry, my server is in Spanish, but basically what it states is that there is an error authenticating the client because the report server is trying to access to a SQL Server with an 'ANONYMOUS LOGON' .. it is possible to authenticate to this last server with my initial credential from the client?

I found this article but I don't understand it completely
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/06/23/my-kerberos-checklist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use kerberos as the article states.  If you can't do that, then you'll have to have the user enter credentials or store some reporting credentials on the server (a sql login).

Perhaps you can ask for clarifications on what you don't comprende.

Comment: Thanks Sam for the answer.. but i really need to send the same credentials from the client to the last server (SQL Server) because that user is granted execution privileges on the SQL .. I cant set up a unique sql login because that will cause that a advance user (un travieso) use the url of the reporting services to view a report that he is not authorize to access ..